linking variable cells to a buttons in excel
I need to link a spin button to a cell, but not a  specific cell, rather a cell which is indicated by a value in another cell.
for example if C2=2 I need it to be linked to B2 and if C2=3 I need it to be linked to B3.
Is that possible in excel?

You can do this by using a named formula that returns a reference to the cell that you want to assign to the control.
You can use formulas like these:
=INDIRECT("B"&$C$2)
=CHOOSE($C$2,,$B$2,$B$3)

References in formulas must be absolute.
When you give a name like link to the formula in Name Manager, you'll need to assign that name to the spinner instead of the address of the associated cell.


. Got it. Thanks a lot for your excellent help
